# Deployment of AdWords Scripts from third party web application using AdWords API

Tags: python-2.7, webapp2, google-ads-api

We are working on a school/client project and developing a web application that can manage MCC AdWords Account effectively and efficiently. 
We are using Python library to communicate with AdWords API. 
I was wandering if there is any way that the scripts written in JavaScript can be deployed to AdWords account using the Web Application and the AdWords API without converting them into Python code. Or is there any other alternative.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adwords has a support to Deploy app Scripts Through API's

You can use deployment services.

Please refer the documentation samples and examples below

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#api_request_examples